# A question about decimal representation of irrational numbers.

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion

Is this true that any finite word of the alphabet $\mathcal{A_9}=\{0,1,2, \ldots,8,9\}$ appears somewhere in the decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$ ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you are trying to ask is if $\sqrt{2}$ is a [normal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number). But while it is widely believed to be so, a proof has yet to be found.

Fun fact: Same goes for $\pi$, and that if true, everything in the universe can be expressed in the decimal digits of $\pi$ or $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was writing as you had finished posting; I may end up deleting my post.

Comment: Saying that $\sqrt 2$ is normal is a much stronger claim than what the8thone is asking about, though it's a very similar proposition.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is the same, or close to, the question of whether $\sqrt 2$ is normal :http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number  This is still open.

Comment: No problem! Keep it and receive a +1.