# Question about irrational numbers and finite subsequences of their decimal places.

Tags: irrational-numbers

A more general question than in "[A question about decimal
representation of irrational
numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822427/a-question-about-decimal-representation-of-irrational-numbers)":
Since there is an infinite amount of irrational numbers could you
always find one that contains a given finite decimal sequence?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can, simply define it to be that way. Take your sequence of digits $a_1a_2...a_n$ and consider the number $0.a_1a_2...a_nb_1b_2...$ where $b_1, b_2...$ are the decimal digits of $\sqrt{2}$. This number will certainly be irrational, because if it was not that would imply $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Comment: Ah, yeah that is indeed a simple solution. Overlooked the fact that there is a trivial solution to this generalization.