# Seeking clarification about another question concerning irrational numbers.

Tags: irrational-numbers

The post [A question about decimal representation of irrational numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/822427/a-question-about-decimal-representation-of-irrational-numbers) asked: "Is this true that any finite word of the alphabet $\mathcal{A_9}=\{0,1,2, \ldots,8,9\}$ appears somewhere in the decimal representation of $\sqrt{2}$ ?" (A)

The given answers say it's a very similar proposition to saying "$\sqrt{2}$ is a normal number." (B)

The phrase "similar" confuses me. It is not equal (A $\iff$ B). So can A be true if $\sqrt{2}$ is an irrational number?

(The start of the sentance in A "Is this true..." suggest that there is probably a source to this question, but I couldn't find anything.)

Comment: Normal numbers are irrational, always. (good exercise) Normality is a stronger property than the simple occurrence of arbitrary strings since it also specifies that each string of a given length is equally probable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, numbers in which every finite sequence of digits occurs are called *disjunctive*, disjunctivity is weaker then normality, in the sense being normal implies being disjunctive but the converse is **not** true.
Take a look at this https://oeis.org/wiki/Disjunctive_numbers for more info.
  As explained in the link $0.10200300000040000000000005...$ *is* disjunctive in Base $10$ but *not* normal.

Comment: So this property is called disjunctive, thank you. I'm just not 100% clear on the "disjunctive in base n" part.

Does it go in the direction of larger bases can't fit into smaller? Would the statement, "If it is disjunctive in base n, it would be disjunctive in all bases k with k < n" be true?

Comment: Which are irrational numbers are known to be disjunctive?

Comment: https://oeis.org/wiki/Champernowne_constant it’s even transcendental.

Comment: Do you know any "non-trivial" that are "like" Pi or Sqrt(2). Or are these kind of numbers unknown to be disjunctive and is this "unknown" an "it is assumed that they are but not proven"?

Comment: Yes, it’s assumed they are disjunctive but not proven.